# Baofeng UV-9G unlock

Tags: baofeng

I have a ham and a gmrs HT.  I read that my GMRS radio can be unlocked, so I don't have to carry two radios with me.  The GMRS radio is a Baofeng UV-9G, SoC radio (so cheap, poor selectivity) but fine for experimenting or high risk activities where I don't want my yaesu to get wet.

I found videos for physically identical models (to my Baofeng UV-9G) which show holding PTT, Monitor, Scan, and then power on, will unlock the unit, removing all tx range limits.

This doesn't seem to work for the UV-9G.  Would anyone know of a button combo to unlock the UV-9G?

Note: Naturally, if you are not authorized to tx on a certain band then don't.  Don't want to start a flame war.

Comment: "Unlocked" to do what?

Comment: Unlocking refers to removing the limits on the tx range.  After unlocking the LCD displays "FACTORY" and then all software limiters on the tx frequency range are removed.

Comment: I was under the impression it was illegal for "hams" to use the baofeng radios. I'm probably wrong about this but I could have sworn I heard it somewhere. I once did something similar, opening a ham radio to work on CB by soldering a jumper and I won't go into any details on that because I'm pretty sure that was not legal.

Comment: I think you are confusing "legal" with FCC rules (in the USA).  As well, both laws and rules allow you to modify your own radio, to listen on any frequency.  If you choose to transmit on that frequency, you should ensure you are authorized.  (And that may violate FCC rules, since radios are designated to run on only certain frequencies; of refered to as part XXX)

Comment: I don't have an answer for the main practical question here, but re. the legality discussion: it would be legal in the US under the Part 97 rules for you to unlock a UV-9G and use it as **ham** radio with the privileges/responsibilities of your amateur license. But being modified it would no longer qualify as a **GMRS** radio under Part 95E. Amateur Radio Service rules are flexible, but on the FRS/GMRS/CB/MURS side if you want to be fully compliant you are only supposed to use a *dedicated* (separate/unmodified) type-approved radio (GMRS radio for GMRS, CB for CB, etc.) on those channels.

Comment: Also the radio I modified and used for years, I never heard any complaints about it and I was using like 10 times the allowed power. It turns out those ham radios are a lot more powerful haha. It even had a built-in roger beep... so cool :D